# automatically change column values to lower case while inserting

Tags: db2

I have a table in db2 which is having a varchar column. I want to insert only lower case string in the column.

Is it possible to change the case to lower whenever an insertion happens in that column. What will be the alter 
Query for that if possible ?

I can not make another column which can take reference of my current column and be referenced like ucase(Current_column)

Comment: There's a couple of ways - some versions of DB2 do support computed columns, or you could do a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.  However, there's a number of problems related to internationalization with casing.  You may want to deal with casing in the application layer (although many languages aren't necessarily better...).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I am using IBM WCS. So can not handle it at application layer. I tried making a BEFORE INSERT, but it is not working as expected. It is working fine if I put queries manually on database but the application is not picking the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The means to ensure the effect of lower-casing the data that is inserted into a column, i.e. *"to change the case to lower whenever an insertion happens in that column"*, is a TRIGGER.

Presumably much like [Why is my “before update” trigger changing unexpected columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050910/why-is-my-before-update-trigger-changing-unexpected-columns), per having noted in a followup comment to the OP that *"I tried making a BEFORE INSERT"*, a TRIGGER similar to the following apparently was implemented in that attempt?:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TOLOWER_BI BEFORE INSERT ON USERS      
REFERENCING NEW AS N OLD AS O FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2ROW
set N.LoginId= lcase(N.LoginId)
```

If so, then "the application is not picking the trigger" [also from a followup comment to the OP] must be explained, because a TRIGGER is in effect at the database layer, such that an *application* has no choice [no *picking*] with regard to the effects of the trigger being enforced.