# Why is my "before update" trigger changing unexpected columns?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, database-trigger

I have a table `USERS` with a `varchar` column `LoginId`. I am trying to use a `before update` trigger to change the incoming value to lower case. This is what I have done so far. It changes the value to lower case. But it also changes all other column to their default values.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TOLOWER BEFORE UPDATE ON USERS 
REFERENCING NEW AS N OLD AS O FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
set N.LoginId= lcase(N.LoginId)
```

Is this trigger correct? If not then what changes should should I do ?

Comment: Looks good to me. What other columns are you talking about - could you give an example? Which OS?

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher I am trying to put this trigger on userreg table in websphere commerce on logonid column. db2 version is 10.5 and i am using wcs 7. http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.database.doc/database/userreg.htm

Comment: Ok I do not have an identical environment but a simple test worked. Have you tried to specify it as AFTER update trigger? Which columns are set to their default? Did they have real values before?

Comment: What does your `UPDATE` statement look like?

Comment: Almost surely not directly relevant to the issue, but, per mention of "to change the incoming value", the desire seems to be for the effect from `CREATE TRIGGER TOLOWER BEFORE UPDATE OF LoginId ON USERS …`; i.e. limit the triggered action to when the value of LoginId is being changed\supplied-with a value. Or to further limit action to when a *new* value: `CREATE TRIGGER TOLOWER BEFORE UPDATE OF loginId ON USERS REFERENCING NEW AS N OLD AS O FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL WHEN(n.loginId<>o.loginID)`

Comment: @mustaccio When i update the database manually, it works fine. But WCS is updating the database out of the box

Comment: So if the UPDATE request being performed when the other columns were set to DEFAULT is unknown, and the effect of the trigger is verified by a test not to exhibit the set-to-default, then how was the trigger "changes all other column to their default values" concluded; i.e. rather than the [seemingly more likely] conclusion that the UDPATE had requested that effect? The trigger should not have that effect of set-to-defaults, and if verified the UPDATE does not make a request to set-to-defaults, then probably the next action to pursue, is support for an apparent defect from a service provider.